# How to put \ in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Iam writing a code that I need to print `\` character. I searched a lot and I saw this solution that to put `"\\"` in a string but the problem is that when printing it will print `\\` not `\` and the same for `|` character.
Anyone know what to do?

I've tried and searched a lot but I didn't find how to print `\` not `\\` or .

Comment: Please show your code. `print('\\')` will work.

Answer (score 4):

`\` in a string starts an [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) which allows using special characters. To use a plain backslash, you need to escape it; in other words, double it up: `"\\"`. This works. When you print the string, it prints a single backslash:

```
>>> print("\\")
\
```

You probably tried printing it by entering the value directly on the Python terminal without calling the `print` function. This will show you a *representation* of the Python value, including quotes and, yes, escape sequences:

```
>>> "\\"
"\\"
```

Note the quotation marks!

An alternative to the above in Python is to use raw string literals. This works everywhere *except* just before a quotation  mark:

```
>>> print(r"\x")
\x
>>> print("r\")
Syntax error
```

By contrast, the pipe character (`|`) is not special. If you want to use it, just put it directly into the string:

```
>>> print("|")
|
```